# How can I make this regex case in-sensitive?

Tags: regex

How can I make this regex case in-sensitive?

```
preg_match('/[\w\d\.]+\.(com|org|ca|net|uk|co|it)/', $string, $matches)
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `.` inside the character class to match a literal dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add case-insensitive modifier `(?i)` to the start of the pattern,

```
(?i)[\w\d\.]+\.(com|org|ca|net|uk|co|it)
```

You code will looks like,

```
preg_match('/(?i)[\w\d\.]+\.(com|org|ca|net|uk|co|it)/', $string, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, adding `i` at the end:

```
preg_match('/[\w\d\.]+\.(com|org|ca|net|uk|co|it)/i', $string, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Two Ways

**A. A Modifier After the Pattern Applies to the Whole Pattern**

Example:

```
$match_or_not = preg_match("~somepattern~i",$subject);
```

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) says this:

> i (PCRE_CASELESS)
>       If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters.

---

**B. An Inline Modifier Can Turn Case-Insensitivity On and Off**

You can apply it to the whole string like so—but you don't have to:

```
$match_or_not = preg_match("~(?i)somepattern~",$subject);
```

You can **turn it off** like so:

```
$match_or_not = preg_match("~(?i)some (?-i)pattern~",$subject);
```

To avoid turning it back on, you can **turn it off temporarily within parentheses**:

```
$match_or_not = preg_match("~(?i)some (?-i:other) pattern~",$subject);
```

---

**From the PCRE doc:**

> The settings of the PCRE_CASELESS, PCRE_MULTILINE, PCRE_DOTALL, and
>   PCRE_EXTENDED options (which are Perl-compatible) can be changed from
>   within the pattern by a sequence of Perl option letters enclosed
>   between "(?" and ")". The option letters are
>
> i  for PCRE_CASELESS   m  for PCRE_MULTILINE   s  for PCRE_DOTALL
>   x  for PCRE_EXTENDED
>
> For example, (?im) sets caseless, multiline matching. It is also
>   possible to unset these options by preceding the letter with a hyphen,
>   and a combined setting and unsetting such as (?im-sx), which sets
>   PCRE_CASELESS and PCRE_MULTILINE while unsetting PCRE_DOTALL and
>   PCRE_EXTENDED, is also permitted. If a letter appears both before and
>   after the hyphen, the option is unset.
>
> The PCRE-specific options PCRE_DUPNAMES, PCRE_UNGREEDY, and PCRE_EXTRA
>   can be changed in the same way as the Perl-compatible options by using
>   the characters J, U and X respectively.
>
> When one of these option changes occurs at top level (that is, not
>   inside subpattern parentheses), the change applies to the remainder of
>   the pattern that follows. If the change is placed right at the start
>   of a pattern, PCRE extracts it into the global options (and it will
>   therefore show up in data extracted by the pcre_fullinfo() function).
>
> An option change within a subpattern (see below for a description of
>   subpatterns) affects only that part of the subpattern that follows it,
>   so
>
> (a(?i)b)c
>
> matches abc and aBc and no other strings (assuming PCRE_CASELESS is
>   not used). By this means, options can be made to have different
>   settings in different parts of the pattern. Any changes made in one
>   alternative do carry on into subsequent branches within the same
>   subpattern. For example,
>
> (a(?i)b|c)
>
> matches "ab", "aB", "c", and "C", even though when matching "C" the
>   first branch is abandoned before the option setting. This is because
>   the effects of option settings happen at compile time. There would be
>   some very weird behaviour otherwise.